# Windows phone 8.1 headset as microphone

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, headset

I still writing Windows Phone application (8.1) to record Audio and Video.
My apk using MediaCapture to record audio and video. Everything work fine, but I still have to find solution to check default phone microphone to headset bluetooth microphone.

I try use AudioEndpoint (but it's not work in 8.1)
I try use

```
var audioDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.AudioCapture);
  var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
```

Next

```
 foreach (var device in audioDevices)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("device id: "+ device.Id+"name: "+device.Name);
        }
```

This code when I use bt headset in phone this code found one device more  while the bt is off. So  I thought that is bt headset mic.

I use

```
  settings.AudioDeviceId = audioDevices[1].Id;
```

But it's not work. Still use default microphone.

Could somebody help me?